# System.Data.EntityException :: "The underlying provider failed on Open." in integration test

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to do an delete entity integration test on my generic repository delete method.

Thats my test delete method:

```
[Test]
public void Delete()
{
    // Arrange
    var user = new User() { FirstName = "test", LastName = "test" };
    var repository = new GenericRepository<User>(_context);
    repository.Add(user);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    // Act
    repository.Delete(user);
    _context.SaveChanges();            

    // Assert
    var deletedUser = _context.Users.Find(user.UserId);
    Assert.Null(deletedUser);
}
```

When I call the _context.SaveChanges after the Delete(user) I get an EntityException:
saying:"System.Data.EntityException :: "The underlying provider failed on Open."

There is surely no problem in accessing my database because I have done an Add test before and I checked that the entity was inserted into the table.

What could cause this problem and why this misleading error message?

These are my 2 repository methods Add and Delete:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
    }
    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public void Delete(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
    else
    {
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

UPDATE

This is the error message of the inner exception:

Test 'TLP.DataAccess.UnitTests.GenericRepositoryTests.Delete' failed: System.Data.EntityException : The underlying provider failed on Open.
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : MSDTC on server 'LISA\SQLEXPRESS' is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the InnerException property of the EntityException. This will give you details as to why the open failed.

Comment: Sorry Craig I thought I pasted everything. I have updated my init question with all information now.

Comment: I had this problem already some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989797/can-not-create-my-dbcontext-in-a-unit-test The solution worked but now I do not pass a constring or name to the my context base class instead I use the conventions and this is the full qualified class name of my context which is put in the name attribute of the connectionstring in the app.config file just like this:  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TLP.DataAccess.TLPContext" ... /> As I said the Add method works only the Delete method not, but what has this to do with the MSDTC ?

Comment: Ok googling around alot and then removing my Transactionscope in the unit test solved the problem. I think cleaning the table from all data before a test is also ok. This question can be closed therefore.